# Inserting a struct variable into a c++ vector inside a loop

Tags: c++

I have a vector of structures called "Cell", which contains a position (x, y), radius, and some other variables.
I need to add more cells to the end of my vector during the program execution as I loop over the vector and check a condition.
Is it safe to create new cells inside the loop and add them to the vector with push_back? Or will this create memory problems as the struct is destroyed(is it?) after the loop is over? the code is more or less the following:

```
for (Cell c : cells) {
    if (my_condition) {
        Cell newc;
        // define cell properties
        cells.push_back(newc);
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please always show a [mcve] when poting example code. In your case, it's obvious, that you can't safely change the `cells` vector while iterating through it at the same time. But in general please obey to post full compilable code, which exactly reproduces the problem you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not safe as the past-end iterator will be invalidated when [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) causes the vector size to increase.

Comment: you're right, push_back breaks everything. I had to create a vector and reserve memory beforehand (with the reserve function) and then inserted the new cells into those reserved position

Answer (score -2):

It will be safe as long the Cell class correctly defines (if needed) copy and move ctors.

If Cell is a POD, it should be all fine.

Comment: No, it's not safe, in case you're modifying the same `std::vector<T>` instance. Doesn't matter if `T` is a POD or not.